# Compiler warning doesn't show up when NSString is passed into NSInteger method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a method:

```
-(void) passWithInteger:(NSInteger)value
```

However when I use this method:

```
[objectInstance passWithInteger:@"bad input string"];
```

There is no compiler error. Is there a way to easily detect that the input is incorrect?

Comment: Are both lines of code in the same .m file? How is `object` declared? Is it `id` or a more specific class?

Comment: Yes they're in the same .m file. The object is based on an instance that was initialized earlier.

Comment: But how is `objectInstance` declared?

Comment: `objectInstance = [self sharedInstance].client`

Comment: No, I'm asking for the declaration (the line like `SomeType *objectInstance`).

Comment: It's from a class that's defined somewhere else. Sorry idk what you're trying to get at.

Comment: @rmaddy I think it has something to do if I declare an NSInteger like this: `NSInteger something = @"Something";` This seems to compile into an NSInteger. Maybe there is no notion of type casting?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have these warnings turned off?

In your target build settings, look for "Implicit Integer to Pointer Conversions" under "Apple LLVM 7.0 - Warnings - All languages". In case it is set to "No" you will not get warnings for these kinds of conversions.